# Perl String to Base36

Tags: perl

How do I convert a string to base36 (0-9,a-z) in perl?

I want to convert IP addresses to base36 with a one to one map, so I can use them in a URL.

`127.0.0.1`
=== string ==> `127000000001` === base36 ==>

`72.98.234.11` 
=== string ==> `072098234011` === base36 ==>

Comment: I found `Math::Base36` but to encode it wants an int as an argument so I was trying to find a way to convert a string to a unique int.

Comment: you can use int($str) or multiply string by 1 to get an int

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't base 10 good enough? That gives a number in [0-4294967295] (1 to 10 digits). That's only slightly longer than what you we were going to get from your way (1 to 8 digits).

```
$ perl -E'say unpack "N", pack "C4", split /\./, $ARGV[0]' 127.0.0.1
2130706433

$ perl -E'say unpack "N", pack "C4", split /\./, $ARGV[0]' 72.98.234.11
1214441995
```

Completely reversible:

```
$ perl -E'say join ".", unpack "C4", pack "N", $ARGV[0]' 2130706433
127.0.0.1

$ perl -E'say join ".", unpack "C4", pack "N", $ARGV[0]' 1214441995
72.98.234.11
```

You could convert that number to another base other than 10 using any number of modules on CPAN.

```
base 10: 1-10 digits
base 16: 1-8 digits    # Can be done very efficiently
base 32: 1-7 digits    # Can be done very efficiently
base 36: 1-7 digits
base 62: 1-6 digits
base 64: 1-6 digits    # Can be done very efficiently
```

Base 16:

```
sub pack_ip { sprintf "%X", unpack "N", pack "C4", split /\./, $_[0] }

sub unpack_ip { join ".", unpack "C4", pack "N", hex $_[0] }
```

Base 64: (This should be quite speedy. Faster even if ported to C.)

```
my @syms = ('0'..'9', 'A'..'Z', 'a'..'z', '_', '-');
my %syms = map { $sym[$_] => $_ } 0..$#syms;

sub pack_ip {
   my $num = unpack "N", pack "C4", split /\./, $_[0];
   my $base64 = join '', @syms[
      ($num >> 30) & 0x3F,
      ($num >> 24) & 0x3F,
      ($num >> 18) & 0x3F,
      ($num >> 12) & 0x3F,
      ($num >>  6) & 0x3F,
      ($num >>  0) & 0x3F,
   ];
   $base64 =~ s/^A+(?!\z)//;
   return $base64;
}

sub unpack_ip {
   my $num;
   $num = ($num << 6) | $sym{$_}
      for split //, $_[0];
   return join ".", unpack "C4", pack "N", $num;
}
```

Comment: This looks like what I needed and actually better because the intermediate int is smaller this way, but I will plug that int to `Math::Base36` and it should produce a string around 6 characters long.
2130706433 => Z8KFLT

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if this gives a one to one map. The split is disregarding the periods, and it could lead to collisions.

Comment: Added more. Yes, one to one map.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that too. I had to read the pack and unpack documentation. Thank you.

Comment: I'm probably not understanding something right but why is it C4 instead of C3? It is packing max 3 character long strings (127,0,1).

Comment: @Emil, You missed a zero. 127,0,0,1. You can think of an IPv4 address as a 4 digit base256 number. Or you can think of it as 4 bytes of a 32 bit number. (Both are the same thing.)

Comment: I was thinking it was packing each character in "127" (1,2,7) into chars which made no sense. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: fyi, max number of digits is obtained using `ceil(ln($max_num)/ln($base))`

Comment: @FlorianB, Your are mistaken, as evidenced by the fact that the answer was accepted. It's just that the original question was poorly worded.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use base 16 since that's basically what an IP address is anyway?

```
sub ip_to_hex {
  join('', map { sprintf('%02x', $_) } split(/\./, shift));
}

sub hex_to_ip {
  join('.', map { hex($_) } shift =~ m/([0-9a-f]{2})/g);
}

say ip_to_hex('127.0.0.1');    # 7f000001
say ip_to_hex('72.98.234.11'); # 4862ea0b
say hex_to_ip('4862ea0b');     # 72.98.234.11
```